# How to use threads to run one activity until another is finished. Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

I Am currently developing an application on VS Xamarin. Currently I am wishing to display a Progress Dialog gif while various methods are loading. This present issue is that the progress dialog appears to freeze for a prior to completion rather than continuously playing until these methods have been executed then disappearing.

This is the code I am using below. I am aware of the Aysnc method however I am unsure how to implement it within an Activity.

```
    progress = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading...", "Uploading This Weeks Lectures", true);

        new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
            this.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                SetData(TodaysDate, out myAdapater);
                FindNotesForWeek(TodaysDate);
                progress.Dismiss();
            });
        })).Start();
```

Comment: You're calling the database on UI thread. Switch to `await` methods

Comment: Hello VMAtm do you have any resources which I could use? when i try using the await method I am unfortunately having no success due to my syntax

Comment: Without showing your method you trying to `await` and you other code there is no way we can help you